# How to pass msg_id into jquery modal form?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a following data where I am showing data from database. When i click Comment a dialog appear, there i need to show data in modal from db. but for getting data from db i need msg_id in modal form.

```
<?php
$msg_id = $data['message_id'];
?>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="msg_id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>#example" class="link_comment">Comment</a>
```

So here I want to pass msg_id to jquery modal form, where i can get data from db on the base of msg_id for that specific message and show it in modal box.

```
<div id="example" class="modal" style="display: none; ">
Your Message id : <?php echo $msg_id; ?>
</div>
```

So how can I pass $msg_id into jquery modal form.

Comment: what is the problem: you don't know how to fetch msg_id from href? or you don't know how to call ajax and return data for specified msg_id?

Comment: Hi, I want to pass msg_id value into Jquery modal.

Comment: You can set a msg_id as hidden field or whatever you want then you can get the msg_id value in modal window.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work or maybe I miss something. Can you give me some example ?

Answer (score 0):

php

```
<?php
$msg_id = 123; // testing mode
?>
```

html

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="msg_id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>#example" class="link_comment">Comment</a>
<div id="example" class="modal" style="display: none; ">
    Your Message id : <span class="msg_id">?</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.link_comment').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this);
        var msg_id = 'fetched id'; // parse msg_id from a.attr('href')
        $('div.' + a.attr('data-toggle')).show().find('span.msg_id').text( msg_id );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it show text like that "Your Message id : fetched id", and 1 things, my modal box can't be hide after I click every where.

Comment: Like in the code comment, parse msg_id from your href. You know how to do that? Second question I don't understand, you want to hide modal box when 2nd click is made to the link?

Comment: Lol. How can I or anyone help you if you don't know what you want?